# How to use the paypal API for direct credit card payment outside the U.S. and UK

Tags: php, api, paypal

Is there a way to make use of the paypal API for direct credit card payment outside the U.S? I've been reading through the docs and I am aware that the REST paypal API for direct credit card doesn't work for the majority of this planet. Which brings me to the 2 things I want to clarify:

1. My impression of things is that the paypal merchant account has to be US based but any person with a credit card can go through paypal to pay for things they want to buy regardless of where they are. Is this accurate?
2. Secondly, could there possibly be a way for me to get a US paypal account, just so I can get things to work, even if my business is in some remote place outside the US or UK. Or do I simply have to forget about paypal when it comes to direct credit card payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are more supported currencies that can make payments TO a valid PayPal direct credit card (DCC) merchant than countries that allow merchants to use the product. You can find a list at the bottom of this page:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/

This is an exhaustive list of supported countries in the PayPal system, but may not apply to customers trying to pay via DCC.

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/country-worldwide

- This would be better addressed to PayPal Merchant Support @ 1-888-215-5506 as there are many different federal regulations in place now that may or may not allow this to happen. From my experience in the customer support department (3+ years ago) we had Canadian merchants with US PayPal accounts with US banks linked and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, no country will give you a bank account if you dont have their visas. That means you wont be able to have a US based Paypal account. Secondly, even if you have a US bank account it will not allow you to accept payments when you are outside the US (I tried this last year and the last two days with no change).